# Why bind a socket to an address?

Tags: sockets

Before 'listen'ing on a socket I must first bind it to an address.  Why?  It seems to me that I shouldn't have to pick and should just listen to that port on all addresses.  Even if I bind to 127.0.0.1 though, it seems I can still connect to that socket from a remote machine.  What does binding to an address really do?

Comment: I would double check that you are actually binded to 127.0.0.1, since you should not be able to connect to a different interface if that was truly the case. If on linux, you could run 'netstat -nlut' to get a pretty output of each service and which address/port it is listening on.

Comment: You're right, something under the hood was actually rewriting 127.0.0.1 as 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Binding to an address defines exactly which interface should have that server port open.
binding to 0.0.0.0 is a special case when you want to listen to all IP addresses know to the interface.
Binding specifically to 127.0.0.1 should make the server port visible **only** to code that can connect to the localhost (e.g. local processes).

Comment: +1, additional info. Binding can be used to only accept local connections. If you have multiple ip addresses you can also have different servers listening on the same port but on different ips.

Comment: @jgauffin Unless these different IP addresses are aliases for the same network interface...am I right? In other words, two servers can't bind to different IP address aliases for the same interface (on the same port). Let me know if you think differently...