# socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99] (Ubuntu on Amazon EC2)

Tags: php, sockets, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to use Sockets on an EC2 Instance, but when I try to run the code I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot
>   assign requested address in sockets_test.php on line 45

Here is part of the relevant code:

```
$CFG = new stdClass();
$CFG->chat_serverip = 'MY_PUBLIC_EC2_IP';
$CFG->chat_serverport = '9111';

$listen_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
socket_bind($listen_socket, $CFG->chat_serverip, $CFG->chat_serverport)
```

This works just fine if I use 127.0.0.1 or the Private IP. 
My Security Group has the the rules:

```
0-65535 0.0.0.0/0 (TCP)
0-65535 0.0.0.0/0 (UDP)
ALL 0.0.0.0/0 (ICMP)
```

Comment: hmmm... it does work if i bind to 0.0.0.0 Is that how it's supposed to work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556811/why-bind-a-socket-to-an-address

Comment: socket binds to your ip (ip of some interface) or 0.0.0.0 (meaning any). This is how you'd define on which interface(s) the socket is reachable. Then you connect (socket_connect) to an IP (for instance 1.1.1.1 IP of cloudflare dns server).

Answer (score 6):

You cannot bind to the external IP, you have to bind to the internal IP, and setup a rule to allow that port so when they connect to the external IP and port, it gets redirected to the internal IP.

Comment: Can you please explain...I am kind of new to this. Little bit explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The **phantomjs** has some question,

we need bind the **internal ip** of We can see at *ifconfig*,
not **external IP** of We can`t see at that.