# php socket bind error

Tags: php, sockets

i trying running php file on my VPS server and i got this error:

```
[agrts@VPS ~]$ php server.php
PHP Warning:  socket_bind(): unable to bind address [99]: Cannot assign requested address in /home/test/server.php on line 10
```

when the ip is 127.0.0.1 i dont get this error but when i change him to my ip or another ips its given me this error, how to fix that? thanks for helpers!

Comment: What port and address are you trying to use? Are sure that your VPS has this IP on one of its interfaces? + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720067/socket-bind-unable-to-bind-address-99-ubuntu-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: one can speculate that perhaps you are trying to bind to a protected port (< 1024) as a non-root process.