# In java, what's the difference between InetAddress.getLocalHost() and InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")

Tags: java, networking, udp

I am using **Windows 8** with **JDK 1.7**. My IP address is 192.168.1.108, when I am running:

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().equals(InetAddress.getByName("localhost")));
```

**OR**

```
System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().equals(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")));
```

Output - It's all false.

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost() - Output: 192.168.1.108      
InetAddress.getByName("localhost") - Output: 127.0.0.1
```

Further more, my UDP server is binded on `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` and it can't receive anything from the client if the client send packets to `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")`. However, it works well if the client send to `InetAddress.getLocalHost().` Port is corrent.

Anyone know the difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably `getLocalHost()` method does name resolution and resolves the address to 127.0.0.1 (or any other ip). So the question becomes: What is the difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382602/what-is-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Comment: Nope, System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("localhost").equals(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"))) gives me true

Comment: Because both `getByNa‌me` and `getLocalhost` methods return you an `InetAddress` object. `equals` method is overridden in `InetAddress` class to return true if IPs are same. 
Check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 2):

From the JDK documentation for getLocalHost():

> Returns the address of the local host. This is achieved by retrieving the name of the host from the system, then resolving that name into an InetAddress.

In my GNU/Linux box, my host name is "laptop", which is mapped to an address different than 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts. There is an equivalent file in Windows at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

By default this hosts file is searched before DNS lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The ad1 gives you your address in your LAN/WAN, it seems
(I mean local/private network IP addresses like e.g. 
192.168.0.108 or like 10.3.6.55).

See also:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost%28%29

But note that ad2 and ad3 are equal in my example.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Test014 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress ad1 = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        InetAddress ad2 = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        InetAddress ad3 = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

        printArr(ad1.getAddress());
        printArr(ad2.getAddress());
        printArr(ad3.getAddress());

        System.out.println(ad1.equals(ad2));
        System.out.println(ad1.equals(ad3));
        System.out.println(ad2.equals(ad3));
    }

    static void printArr(byte[] arr){
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            System.out.print("[" + i + "] = " + arr[i] + "; ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("---------");
    }

}
```

Also, check the API docs about when the equals method returns true and when false.

http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Now I understand why equal return false. But I've only one network adaptor. The packet sent to 127.0.0.1 should also be received if I bind udp socket on 192.168.1.108, am I right?

Comment: I think - not really. See here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556811/why-bind-a-socket-to-an-address I know that servers usually have special flag/switch to tell them to listen on all known addresses/interfaces. And you're practically writing a server. So it does matter on which address or addresses you have your server port open for incoming connections. –  peter.petrov 5 mins ago