# How does a Python listening socket get setup?

Tags: python, sockets

When you setup a simple TCP listening socket using the Python 'socket' module, what are the different steps involved doing?

The code I'm talking about looks like this:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 50000))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

The `s = ...` seems pretty straightforward - you are expressing your intent to create an ipv4 TCP socket, without having done anything yet.

What I'm curious about is this:

- What does it mean to bind to a socket, without listening?
- How does limiting the number of unaccepted connections using `listen(n)` work?

  - If you have listen(1), you're in the middle of dealing with the first connection you accepted, and a second client tries to connect, is the second client waiting for the SYN-ACK? Or does the 3 way handshake happen, and he's waiting for actual data?
  - What happens if a third client tries to connect - does he immediately get a TCP RST?
  - Does setting the number of unaccepted connections here set some option in the kernel to indicate how many connections it should accept? Or is this all handled in Python?
- How can you be listening without accepting? What does it mean to accept a connection?

Every article I've come across seems to just assume these steps make sense to everyone, without explaining what exactly it is that each one does. They just use generic terms like

> listen() starts listening for connections
>
> bind() binds to a socket
>
> accept() just accepts the connection

Defining a word by using that word in the definition is kind of a dumb way to explain something.

Comment: Related - [Why bind a socket to an address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556811/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's basically a 1-to-1 from the POSIX c calls and as such I'm including links to the man pages, so that you can read their explanation and corresponding c code:

[socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) creates a communication endpoint by means of a file-descriptor in the namespace of the address-family you specified but assigns neither address nor port.

[bind](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) assigns an address and port to said socket, a port which may be chosen randomly if you request a port for which you do not have the privilige. (like < 1024 for non-root user)

[listen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html) makes the specific socket and hence address and port a passive one, meaning that it will accept incoming connections with the accept call. To handle multiple connections one after the other, you get to specify a backlog containing them, connections that arrive while you're handling one get appended. Once the backlog is full, the system will respond as such to those systems with an approach that makes them reconnect by withholding SYN, withholding ACK response etc..

As usual you can find someone [explaining the previous](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html) to you a lot better.

[accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) then creates a new non-listening socket associated with a new file descriptor that you then use for communication with said connecting party.
accept also works as a director for your flow of execution, effectively blocking further progress until a connection is actually available in the queue for it to take, like a spinlock. The only way around that is to declare the socket non-blocking in which case it would return immediately with an error.

Comment: Small correction: `bind` does not choose a port randomly if you request a port for which you don't have the privilege. The bind will simply fail with `EPERM`, leaving the socket unbound. If you attempt to *use* a socket in a way that requires an address to be established (even for `listen`) and you have *not* previously bound it successfully, *then* the system will choose a "random" port for you.