# Spring boot change the IP address of server with my LAN IP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

trying to use the IP address of LAN instead of the localhost domain name.

I have added the property **server.address** in the **application.properties** file like in image:

[image]

but this show me an error:

```
2021-08-26 13:30:36.479  INFO 4246 --- [           main] c.v.s.SmappapikiviApplication            : Starting SmappapikiviApplication using Java 11.0.10 on KO-PRI-VSK-L003 with PID 4246 (/home/matr/Projects/smapp-api-kivi/target/classes started by matr in /home/matr)
2021-08-26 13:30:36.487  INFO 4246 --- [           main] c.v.s.SmappapikiviApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-26 13:30:42.873  INFO 4246 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-26 13:30:44.062  INFO 4246 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1141 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-08-26 13:30:47.493  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-08-26 13:30:47.561  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-26 13:30:47.570  INFO 4246 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-08-26 13:30:48.165  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-26 13:30:48.166  INFO 4246 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11333 ms
2021-08-26 13:30:49.291  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-08-26 13:30:49.519  INFO 4246 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-08-26 13:30:50.209  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-08-26 13:30:50.871  INFO 4246 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-08-26 13:30:52.737  INFO 4246 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-08-26 13:30:52.948  INFO 4246 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-08-26 13:30:56.177  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-08-26 13:30:56.230  INFO 4246 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-26 13:30:59.108  WARN 4246 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-08-26 13:31:02.123  WARN 4246 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
2021-08-26 13:31:02.255  INFO 4246 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-26 13:31:02.270  INFO 4246 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-08-26 13:31:02.431  INFO 4246 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-08-26 13:31:02.439  INFO 4246 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-08-26 13:31:02.504  INFO 4246 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-26 13:31:02.648 ERROR 4246 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at com.vamed.smappapikivi.SmappapikiviApplication.main(SmappapikiviApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:243) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.5.3.jar:2.5.3]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.50.jar:9.0.50]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

How to fix this problem or is this possible to run the java project in the LAN IP Address?

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): you try to access your application from your LAN and the solution you found is to bind your application to a specific IP address (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7556811/11748454)). By default Spring Boot listens on all interfaces/addresses, remove the `server.address` property or set it to an empty string.

Comment: I am at the same point right now, changing server.address causes org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException. Any any new insights? Cheers Tim